# Why are my Makefile variables inconstant after using tr?

Tags: linux, variables, makefile, tr

I'm working on a Makefile which takes a command line parameter, runs a translation ([`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)) on it, then uses that variable to create a directory and also prints the result. When the variable is printed, it is as I expect (the translated name), however when the variable is used to create the directory, the results are incorrect.

So for example, when I run:

```
make build=debug
```

I see:

```
Building...
***************************
BuilD Type:       Debug
Build Target:     x86
```

But the resultant file system is:

```
out/
 └─── debug | tr d D_x86
```

I **thought** that running the [translation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) on the input variable `build` and assigning it to `$BUILD_TYPE` would have set this new variable to `"Debug"` but it seems like that is not the case all the time... How does this actually work?

---

Full Makefile:

```
BUILD_TYPE=Release
BUILD_TARGET=Arm
OUTPUT_DIR=out

MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

ifeq ($(build),debug)
    BUILD_TYPE='$(build) | tr d D'
endif
ifeq ($(target),x86)
    BUILD_TARGET=$(target)
endif

TT=$(BUILD_TYPE)_$(BUILD_TARGET)

all: directories
    @echo 'Building...'
    @echo '***************************'
    @echo 'Build Type:       $(BUILD_TYPE)'
    @echo 'Build Target:     $(BUILD_TARGET)'
    @echo 'Output Directory: $(PWD)/$(OUTPUT_DIR)'
    @echo '***************************'

directories:
    ${MKDIR_P} $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    ${MKDIR_P} $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
BUILD_TYPE='$(build) | tr d D'
```

is not running a shell command. That is a literal string assignment.

You are assigning to the variable `BUILD_TYPE` the **literal** string `'debug | tr d D'`.

To do what you want you need to actually run a shell command. Something like this for example.

```
BUILD_TYPE:=$(shell echo '$(build)' | tr d D)\
```

As to why you are seeing things "correctly" on the output line that's because you happen to be generating a valid shell pipeline there and make is running it.

That is this line

```
@echo 'Build Type:       $(BUILD_TYPE)'
```

becomes

```
@echo 'Build Type:       'debug | tr d D''
```

which, you'll notice, is a valid shell line. Also notice that you get `BuilD type` and not `Build type` printed out?

Comment: AH... ok. So the reason the output looked correct is because when the `@echo` was running, it ran the shell command in `$BUILD_TYPE` (ie the `tr`)?

Comment: Thanks very much, that explains it, updating the `$BUILD_TYPE` assignment with the shell command resolved both the output directory name and the uppercase 'D' in `"BuilD type"`. I missed that incorrect print out.

Comment: @Mike I will point out that there's really no reason to use `$(shell)` for this since the input and output are both known static strings. Save the shell, sub-shell and tr invocations and just use `BUILD_TYPE=Debug` instead. =)

Comment: Yes, in this instance, that's true. This Makefile(/system) is going to get a lot more complex soon (as you can see it doesn't even build anything right now!) and I was thinking of other applications for this construct but I thought I'd test it out in the simple case first.